# Opening File with backslash in name, using a variable in bash

Tags: bash, variables, filenames, fastq

A complicated name for a simple question.   I am trying to make an idiot proof program for people I work with when I am gone.  I am using read to save a file name as a variable.  When I **drag and drop** a file from a fold who's name has a space (and hence a backslash) it won't work.  If I type the name straight in it works.  Examples below.

```
$ read -re a
/Users/microuser/Desktop/han\ scans/D2GDVACXX_s8_0_7bp_Index_9_SL39794.fastq 
$ echo $a
/Users/microuser/Desktop/han\ scans/D2GDVACXX_s8_0_7bp_Index_9_SL39794.fastq
$ echo "$a"
/Users/microuser/Desktop/han\ scans/D2GDVACXX_s8_0_7bp_Index_9_SL39794.fastq
$ head $a
head: /Users/microuser/Desktop/han\: No such file or directory
head: scans/D2GDVACXX_s8_0_7bp_Index_9_SL39794.fastq: No such file or directory
$ head "$a"
head: /Users/microuser/Desktop/han\ scans/D2GDVACXX_s8_0_7bp_Index_9_SL39794.fastq: No such file or directory
```

however if I type it in instead of using a variable.

```
$ head -n 1 /Users/microuser/Desktop/han\ scans/D2GDVACXX_s8_0_7bp_Index_9_SL39794.fastq 
@HWI-ST1280:209:D2GDVACXX:8:1101:2762:1973 1:Y:0:GATCAGA
```

if I take the space out of the folder name using the variable works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put backslash before space while reading the input and avoid using `-r` option as `-r` option says *do not allow backslashes to escape any characters*.

This should work:

```
$ read -e a
/Users/microuser/Desktop/han scans/D2GDVACXX_s8_0_7bp_Index_9_SL39794.fastq 
$ head "$a"
```

Comment: This makes some sense.  How can I get the terminal from adding the backslash when the file is dropped onto it.

Comment: The problem appears to be a quirk of using drag and drop + `read`.  When I invoke `read` and then enter the name in with the backslashes, it correctly treats it exactly like your sample above.

Comment: oh so are you using this in conjunction with a drag-drop operation? Can you please clarify the steps you're doing

Comment: The steps are `read -e a` then drag the file to terminal which prints what I've shown above in the example.  When I use read and type in the files, it works just fine even with the backslashes as it should.  I'll fiddles some more when I have access to a Mac again, as cygwin doesn't act the same as the mac terminal.

Comment: I am a mac user myself. What are the steps I need to follow to reproduce this error?

Comment: I figured it out...  the -r flag in read is a typo and the reason for the problem.  -r in read means -r do not allow backslashes to escape any characters

Comment: Ah ok, great to know you resolved your problem (I updated my answer)

Answer (score 2):

The filename does *not* contain a backslash, only a space. The backslash is only present because some application will helpfully use/show the *pre-escaped* version, like in bash's auto-completion.

The following examples should hopefully clarify this:

```
# touch "some file.txt"
# ls -lsa som*
0 -rw-rw-r--. 1 foo bar 0 Oct  9 13:49 some file.txt

# read var
some file.txt

# echo $var
some file.txt

# ls -lsa $var
ls: cannot access some: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access file.txt: No such file or directory

# ls -lsa "$var"
0 -rw-rw-r--. 1 foo bar 0 Oct  9 13:49 some file.txt

# ls -lsa some\ file.txt
0 -rw-rw-r--. 1 foo bar 0 Oct  9 13:49 some file.txt

# ls -lsa "some file.txt"
0 -rw-rw-r--. 1 foo bar 0 Oct  9 13:49 some file.txt
```

Comment: if you had taken the time to read more than the title of my question you would have known I already knew this.  Also you didn't answer my question, in fact all you did was reproduce my problem.

Comment: Adding backslashes has no effect when typing it into read for example if I use `read -e var` then enter `some\ file.txt`, `echo $var` gives `some file.txt`and is evaluated correctly by the read command then evaluate it with `head "$var", which is why this is odd... I am guessing the mac OS is doing something when I drag and drop the file into the terminal with read.